# Cannot pass Object which extend of a abstract one into a Method with the abstract Object as Parameter

Tags: java, list, generics, generic-programming, generic-collections

Here's the code of the method:

```
public void setupList(ArrayList<AnyAbstractObject> list)
{
     //Here´s the Code stuff. This Method is in the Class: AlphabeticList
}
```

And I tried to call this method with:

```
setUpList(new ArrayList<THEObject>);
```

The Code of THEObject:

```
public class THEObject extends AnyAbstractObject{//Lalala}
```

When I'm trying to run this program the console prints this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> The method setupList(AnyAbstractObject[]) in the type AlphabeticList is not applicable for the arguments (AlphabeticList)
>
> at Test.Tester.main(Tester.java:22)

What is the issue here?

Comment: there are several issues. Forget about the type, why you are passing a list when it is begging for an array.

Comment: `[]` is not the same thing as `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Bruno You can hover over the down vote button to understand their purpose.

Comment: I am taking that into account.

Comment: That wasnt my source code... i did an error while copying the Method, i corrcted it, sorry :)

Comment: @N.J.Funk ,  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ArrayList<THEObject>` is not an `ArrayList<AnyAbstractObject>`, even though an `THEObject` is an `AnyAbstractObject`. Here's the catch:

Every cat is an animal. Is every "*room full of cats*" a "*room full of animals*"?

At first, it seems so. But it isn't. There are stuff you can definitely do with one, but not with the other. For instance, you can take a random individual from a "*room full of cats*" and cuddle it. But this isn't something you can safely do with a "*room full of animals*" (beware the bugs, alligators, etc...)

In Java, we would have the class hierarchy `public class Cat extends Animal`. And "do stuff with" is to apply a method.

While you know every individual element you take from an `ArrayList<Cat>` is a `Cat`:

```
 ArrayList<Cat> roomFullOfCats = getKittens();
 Cat tom = roomFullOfCats.get(42);
```

you can't expect that an individual element you take from an `ArrayList<Animal>` is a `Cat`

```
 ArrayList<Animal> roomFullOfAnimals = getAnimals();
 Animal jerry = roomFullOfAnimals.get(0); // <-- perfectly legal
 Cat tom = roomFullOfAnimals.get(42); //  <-- fails
```

These are the slippers slopers of Generic Programming, and the [Java Tutorial chapter on Generic Programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) covers them elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

setupList and setUpList are not the same methods. Java is case sensitive.